# Every Category Is Invalid eBay API

Tags: ebay-api

I tried asking this on the ebay forums, but I haven't had a response yet.  For some reason I can no longer list products with the API.

It was working in the past.  I'm sending the following headers still:

```
$headers = array(
        'X-EBAY-API-SITEID:'.$this->siteId,
        'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL:'.$this->version,
        'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME:'.$action,
   );
```

When I'm adding 'action' is 'AddItem', and the version is set to '989'.  An example request that I send looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AddItemRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>[[removed]]</eBayAuthToken>
</RequesterCredentials>
<ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
<Item>
    <Title>dewalt battery test</Title>
    <Description>this is a test battery</Description>
    <PrimaryCategory>
        <CategoryID>27029</CategoryID>
    </PrimaryCategory>
    <StartPrice>65</StartPrice>
    <Country>US</Country>
    <Currency>USD</Currency>
    <ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>
    <DispatchTimeMax>2</DispatchTimeMax>
    <ListingDuration>Days_7</ListingDuration>
    <ListingType>FixedPriceItem</ListingType>
    <PictureDetails/>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
    <PostalCode>47714</PostalCode>
    <ReturnPolicy>
        <ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>
        <RefundOption>MoneyBack</RefundOption>
        <ReturnsWithinOption>Days_30</ReturnsWithinOption>
        <Description>If you are not satisfied, return the book for refund.</Description>
        <ShippingCostPaidByOption>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidByOption>
    </ReturnPolicy>
    <ShippingDetails>
        <ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>
        <ShippingServiceOptions>
            <ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>
            <ShippingService>USPSPriority</ShippingService>
            <ShippingServiceCost>2.50</ShippingServiceCost>
            <ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>2.50</ShippingServiceAdditionalCost>
        </ShippingServiceOptions>
    </ShippingDetails>
    <Site>US</Site>
    <UUID>[[removed]]</UUID>
    <PaymentMethods>PayPal</PaymentMethods>
    <PayPalEmailAddress>[[removed]]</PayPalEmailAddress>
</Item>
</AddItemRequest>
```

And the response I get looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AddItemResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
<Timestamp>2017-05-11T00:34:05.364Z</Timestamp>
<Ack>Failure</Ack>
<Errors>
    <ShortMessage>Category is not valid.</ShortMessage>
    <LongMessage>The category is not valid, select another category.</LongMessage>
    <ErrorCode>107</ErrorCode>
    <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
    <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
</Errors>
<Errors>
    <ShortMessage>Condition is not applicable.</ShortMessage>
    <LongMessage>Condition is not applicable for this category. The condition value submitted has been dropped.</LongMessage>
    <ErrorCode>21917121</ErrorCode>
    <SeverityCode>Warning</SeverityCode>
    <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
</Errors>
<Version>1011</Version>
<Build>E1011_UNI_API5_18405133_R1</Build>
</AddItemResponse>
```

I've gotten the condition warning before and was still able to list.  This is the first time that all categories have been failing.  Just for testing, I even tried getting the list of categories, and only pulling the ones that I knew from the API were leaf categories, such as the following:

```
 [BestOfferEnabled] => true
 [AutoPayEnabled] => true
 [CategoryID] => 183073
 [CategoryLevel] => 3
 [CategoryName] => Other Virtual Reality Accs
 [CategoryParentID] => 183067
 [LeafCategory] => true
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.  The account I'm using doesn't appear to have any restrictions and is not suspended, which is the first thing I thought.  Could this "Invalid Category" be an indication of a different problem?  Switching categories doesn't seem to be fixing it.

I can not find a single category that does work, however, a list of some that I have tried include the following: 20374 -> Other Hand Tools, 21555 -> Unisex Shoes,  and 19488 -> Baby Books, 21027 -> Water Filtration

Comment: I am also seeing this for the first time, occassionally when using the VerifyAddFixedPriceItem API.  Out of say 120 calls, I will get 8 failures of this 21555 error code.   Did you ever find a root cause?

Comment: It looks like they were actually invalid categories.  In my instance I had it stored in the database and I had "id" as the actual key and "ebay_category_id".  My code was trying to use the "id" which ebay didn't recognize.

It could be that in your application the category ids have changed since you last pulled them.

Answer (score 0):

Category **20374 - Other Hand Tools** was a while back changed to 20357. I was able to find that out by calling GetCategoryMappings on the TradingAPI ([link](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/Reference/eBay/GetCategoryMappings.html)). Here is where I found the occurance

[image]

Keep in mind the longer you leave old category mappings, the further you'll have to call back the `CategoryVersion` property (for this result I had to go as far back as v68).

Hope this helps!

Koda